# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 ax}{x(1-e^x)}dx=\frac{1}{4}\log\left( \frac{2a\pi}{\sinh 2a\pi}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

How can we prove this ${\it{interesting}}$ integral
$$
I:=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 ax}{x(1-e^x)}dx=\frac{1}{4}\log\left( \frac{2a\pi}{\sinh 2a\pi}\right)
$$
I to write
$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{(1-\cos a x)}{x}dx \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nx}
$$
simplifying
$$
I=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nx}\frac{dx}{x} -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos a x}{x}dx \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{nx}
$$
but didn't help much.  Thank you

Comment: I suggest you use differentiation under the integral sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(ax)}{x(1-e^{x})} \ dx.
\end{align}
This can be seen as
\begin{align}
- I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{-x} \sin^{2}(ax) }{ x ( 1 - e^{-x}) } \ dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(n+1)x} \sin^{2}(ax) \ \frac{dx}{x} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I_{n}
\end{align}
where $I_{n}$ is given by
\begin{align}
I_{n} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(n+1)x} \sin^{2}(ax) \ \frac{dx}{x}.
\end{align}
Now $I_{n}$ can be evaluated as follows.
\begin{align}
\partial_{n} I_{n} &= - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(n+1)x} \sin^{2}(ax) \ dx \\
&= - \frac{1}{2} \ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(n+1)x} (1 - \cos(2ax)) \ dx \\
&= - \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{(n+1)}{4a^{2} + (n+1)^{2}} \right] 
\end{align}
and upon integration yields
\begin{align}
I_{n} &= - \frac{1}{2} \ln(n+1) + \frac{1}{4} \ln (4 a^{2} + (n+1)^{2}) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \ln\left( \frac{4 a^{2} + (n+1)^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}} \right). 
\end{align}
Now, returning to the summation, it is seen that
\begin{align}
- I &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ln\left( \frac{4 a^{2} + (n+1)^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \ln \left( \prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \left\{ \frac{4 a^{2} + (n+1)^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}} 
\right\} \right).
\end{align}
Using the product formula
\begin{align}
\frac{\sinh(x)}{x} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{k^{2} \pi^{2}} \right)
\end{align}
then the final result is
\begin{align}
I = \frac{1}{4} \ln \left( \frac{2 a \pi}{\sinh(2a \pi)} \right). 
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(ax)}{x(1-e^{x})} \ dx = \frac{1}{4} \ln \left( \frac{2 a \pi}
{\sinh(2a \pi)} \right).
\end{align}

Comment: Do you have proof of the product formula$$
\frac{\sinh(x)}{x} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x^{2}}{k^{2} \pi^{2}} \right),
$$
or a reference to it?  This is a great solution very nice work again, thanks for solving another integral. +1

Comment: In the article http://www.math.binghamton.edu/dikran/478/Ch6.pdf the formula is on page 328. Also in the Table of Integrals, Series, and Products it is formula 1.431.2 page 45 (5th ed).

Comment: I believe you that the formula is correct.  I want to know if you have reference to a proof, or can prove it.  I looked at pg. 328 it is very nice but it is an exercise to prove, not the proof.  Thanks again...

Comment: In Whittaker and Watson's book, p. 137, the general product formula is given with application to show the sine infinite product, then shift by $x = it$ https://archive.org/details/courseofmodernan00whit . Another way to do the infinite product is to use the Gamma function infinite product form and use $\Gamma(x) \Gamma(-x) = - \frac{\pi}{x \sin(\pi x)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the references, that is is a bit more helpful to me.  And the solution again.  +1

Answer (score 9):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}{\frac {\partial }{\partial a}}\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\cos
 \left( 2\,ax \right) -1}{x \left( -1+{{\rm e}^{x}} \right) }}{dx}&=
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {\sin \left( 2\,ax \right) }{1-{{\rm e}^{x
}}}}{dx}\\
&=\mathcal{Im} \left( \int _{0}^{\infty }\!-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{2\,iax}}}{-1+{
{\rm e}^{x}}}}{dx} \right) \\
&=\mathcal{Im}\left(\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left( \int _{0}^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{2\,iax}}{
{\rm e}^{-xn}}{dx} \right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\,i\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(  \frac{1}{\left( 2\,ia-n \right)} 
 \frac{1}{\left( -2\,ia-n \right)} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4\,a}+\frac{\pi}{2} \,\coth \left( 2\,\pi \,a \right)   
\end{aligned}$$
Integrating with respect to $a$ gives:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 ax}{x(1-e^x)}dx&=\int \!\frac{1}{4\,a}+\frac{\pi}{2} \,\coth \left( 2\,\pi \,a \right) {da}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\,\ln  \left( 2\,\pi \,a \right) +\frac{1}{4}\,\ln  \left( \sinh \left( 2\,
\pi \,a \right)  \right)+K\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\,\ln  \left( \frac{2\,\pi \,a }{\sinh \left( 2\,
\pi \,a \right) }\right)+K 
\end{aligned}$$ 
and the constant of integration $K$, is zero as: $$\lim _{a\rightarrow 0}{\frac {2\pi \,a}{\sinh \left( 2\,\pi \,a
 \right) }}=1,\quad \lim_{a=0}\,\sin^2(ax)=0$$

The integral:
$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{2\,iax}}}{-1+{
{\rm e}^{x}}}}{dx} $$
can also be evaluated by comparing it to the difference of two [digamma functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and then the $\coth$ function appears using the reflection formula for the digamma function.

Comment: Also +1 on the command $\mathcal{Im}$, I always used $\Im$ and it doesn't look nearly as nice.  Nice work:).  Also having gone through this method in detail now, it seems your starting point is more of a magician's style:)!   Any insight as to how you start there? Thanks!

Comment: I thought the integral would resemble something familiar were it not for the $1/x$ term. I saw the parameter $a$ and asked what happens if I differentiate w.r.t to $a$? Agh, that gets rid of the annoying $1/x$... this technique is known as differentiation under the integral it also features in Leucippus's answer and Zaid alluded to it in his comment.

Comment: Ok thanks for the assistance and help

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{I\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin^{2}\pars{ax} \over x\pars{1 - \expo{x}}}\,\dd x
     ={1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2a\pi \over \sinh\pars{2a\pi}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> I&=\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {1 - \expo{2\ic ax} \over 1 - \expo{x}}\,\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t\,\dd x
> =-\,\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\pars{1 - \expo{2\ic ax}}\expo{-x} \over 1 - \expo{-x}}\,
> \expo{-tx}\,\dd x\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> \expo{-\pars{n + 1 + t}x} - \expo{-\pars{n + 1 + t - 2\ic a}x}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
> {1 \over n + 1 + t} - {1 \over n + 1 + t - 2\ic a}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{{1 \over -2\ic a}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 1 + t}\pars{n + 1 + t - 2\ic a}}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 + t} - \Psi\pars{1 + t - 2\ic a}}
> \,\dd t
> \end{align}
>   where $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \equiv \totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z}}}{z}}$ is the
>   [Digamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.1}}$ and we have used the [identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.3.16}}$. $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
>   [Gamma Function](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_255.htm) ${\bf\mbox{6.1.1}}$.

With [Stirling Asymptotic Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_257.htm)
${\bf\mbox{6.1.41}}$:
$$
I=\half\,\bracks{\overbrace{%
\Re\lim_{t \to \infty}\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 + t} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + t - 2\ic a}}}
^{\ds{=\ 0}}
+\Re\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 - 2\ic a}}}
$$

> With [identities](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm)
>   ${\bf\mbox{6.1.28}}$ and ${\bf\mbox{6.1.29}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> I&=\half\,{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1 - 2\ic a}\Gamma\pars{1 + 2\ic a}} \over 2}
> ={1 \over 4}\,
> \ln\pars{\pars{-2\ic a}\Gamma\pars{-2\ic a}\pars{2\ic a}\Gamma\pars{2\ic a}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{4a^{2}\verts{\Gamma\pars{2\ic a}}^{2}}
> ={1 \over 4}\,\,\ln\pars{4a^{2}\,{\pi \over 2a\sinh\pars{2\pi a}}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
I\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin^{2}\pars{ax} \over x\pars{1 - \expo{x}}}\,\dd x={1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2a\pi \over \sinh\pars{2a\pi}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{{\sin }^2}ax}}{{x\left( {1 - {e^x}} \right)}}dx}  =  - \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{1 - \cos 2ax}}{{x\left( {{e^x} - 1} \right)}}dx}  =  - \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {1 - \cos 2ax} \right){e^{ - x}}}}{{x\left( {1 - {e^{ - x}}} \right)}}dx}  =  - \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {1 - \cos 2ax} \right){e^{ - x}}}}{x}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{e^{ - nx}}} dx}  = $$

$$\displaystyle  =  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{\left( {1 - \cos 2ax} \right){e^{ - \left( {n + 1} \right)x}}}}{x}dx} }  =  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {1 - \cos 2ax} \right){e^{ - \left( {n + 1} \right)x}}\left( {\int\limits_0^\infty  {{e^{ - yx}}dy} } \right)dx} }  = $$

$$\displaystyle  =  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {1 - \cos 2ax} \right){e^{ - \left( {n + 1 + y} \right)x}}dx} } \right)dy} }  =  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{{n + 1 + y}} - \frac{{n + 1 + y}}{{4{a^2} + {{\left( {n + 1 + y} \right)}^2}}}} \right)dy} }  = $$

$$\displaystyle  =  - \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\left[ {\log \frac{{{{\left( {n + 1 + y} \right)}^2}}}{{4{a^2} + {{\left( {n + 1 + y} \right)}^2}}}} \right]_0^\infty }  =  - \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\log \frac{{{n^2}}}{{4{a^2} + {n^2}}}}  =  - \frac{1}{4}\log \mathop {\lim }\limits_{{\rm N} \to \infty } \frac{{{{\left( {{\rm N}!} \right)}^2}}}{{\prod\limits_{n = 1}^N {\left( { - 2ia + n} \right)} \prod\limits_{n = 1}^N {\left( {2ia + n} \right)} }} = $$

$$\displaystyle  =  - \frac{1}{4}\log \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\frac{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{ - 2ia}} \cdot n! \cdot \left( { - 2ia} \right)}}{{\left( { - 2ia} \right)\left( { - 2ia + 1} \right)\left( { - 2ia + 2} \right)..\left( { - 2ia + n} \right)}} \cdot \frac{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^{2ia}} \cdot n!\left( {2ia} \right)}}{{\left( {2ia} \right)\left( {2ia + 1} \right)\left( {2ia + 2} \right)..\left( {2ia + n} \right)}}} \right) = $$

$$\displaystyle  =  - \frac{1}{4}\log \left( { - 4 \cdot {i^2}{a^2}\Gamma \left( {2ia} \right)\Gamma \left( { - 2ia} \right)} \right) =  - \frac{1}{4}\log \left( {4{a^2}\frac{{\Gamma \left( {2ia} \right)\Gamma \left( {1 - 2ia} \right)}}{{ - 2ia}}} \right) =  - \frac{1}{4}\log \left( {4{a^2}\frac{\pi }{{ - 2ia \cdot \sin \left( {2\pi ia} \right)}}} \right) = $$

$$\displaystyle  =  - \frac{1}{4}\log \left( {2a\frac{\pi }{{ - i \cdot \dfrac{{{e^{ - 2\pi a}} - {e^{2\pi a}}}}{{2i}}}}} \right) \Rightarrow \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{{\sin }^2}ax}}{{x\left( {1 - {e^x}} \right)}}dx}  = \log \sqrt[{^4}]{{\frac{{{e^{2\pi a}} - {e^{ - 2\pi a}}}}{{4a\pi }}}}$$

$$
\text{Due to the square, we can consider } a \ge 0.
$$

[i][u]The following formulas were used:[/u][/i]  $$ \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-ax} \,dx = \frac{1}{a} $$ and $$ \int\limits_0^\infty \cos(bx) \cdot e^{-ax} \,dx = \frac{a}{b^2 + a^2} $$ (elementary exponential integrals)
as well as $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{(n + 1)^z \cdot n!}{z(z + 1)(z + 2) \ldots (z + n)} \right) = \Gamma(z), $$  $$ \Gamma(1 + z) = z \cdot \Gamma(z) $$ and $$ \Gamma(z) \cdot \Gamma(1 - z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} $$ from here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html.