# Evaluation of $4\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\left(\sinh\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)\right)^2}{x(e^x-1)}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In relation with [Evaluating series of zeta values like $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2k)}{k16^{k}}=\ln(\pi)-\frac{3}{2}\ln(2) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857455/evaluating-series-of-zeta-values-like-sum-k-1-infty-frac-zeta2kk16)

From the well-known formula,

For $s$, such that $\Re(s)>1$,

$\displaystyle \zeta(s)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$

it follows that,

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2k)}{k16^{k}}=4\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{\left(\sinh\left(\tfrac{x}{8}\right)\right)^2}{x(e^x-1)}dx$

Is it possible to evaluate directly the latter integral?

Comment: Looks like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803363/integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin2-axx1-exdx-frac14-log-left-frac?rq=1) with $a= i/8.$

Comment: try abel plana!

Comment: @FDP Please, can you explain what's wrong with the answers below?

Answer (score 9):

An approach.

**Hint**. One may set
$$
f(s):=4\int_0^\infty \frac{\left(\sinh\left(sx\right)\right)^2}{x(e^x-1)}dx, \quad 0<s<\frac12. \tag1
$$ By differentiating with respect to $s$ one gets
$$
\begin{align}
f'(s)&=4\int_0^\infty \frac{\sinh\left(2sx\right)}{e^x-1}dx
\\\\&=2\int_0^\infty\left(e^{2sx}-e^{-2sx}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}dx
\\\\&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty\left(e^{2sx}-e^{-2sx}\right) e^{-nx}dx
\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8s}{n^2-4s^2}
\\\\&=\frac1s-2\pi\cot(2\pi s) \tag2
\end{align}
$$ 
Integrating $(2)$, with the fact that, as $s \to 0$, $f(s) \to 0$, we get

> $$
> \int_0^\infty \frac{\left(\sinh\left(sx\right)\right)^2}{x(e^x-1)}dx=\log \left(\frac{2\pi s}{\sin(2\pi s)}\right), \quad 0<s<\frac12, \tag4
> $$

from which you deduce the value of the given integral by putting $s:=\color{blue}{\frac18}$, which is $\color{blue}{\ln(\pi)-\frac32\ln 2}$.

*Remark*. With the general parameter $s$, we have obtained a little bit more than the initial integral.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please indicate the reason. I upvoted, because I don't see anything wrong with this answer

Comment: @You're In My Eye and Jack D'Aurizio good Job (+1) for all

Comment: So he differentiates the integrand. Gets an integral that evaluates to a function that has pole at the value he wants to integrate to and then goes and just permutes the derivative with the integral. This needs some analysis to justify the permutation of the derivative with the integral. It's far from obvious.

Comment: @zzchan The function has *no pole at all* at the value we are looking for, that is at $s=\frac18$. This function is analytic over $(0,\frac12)$, to say the least. Isn't it? I'm sorry but what you wrote above is wrong. The permutation between $\sum$ and $\int$ may be obtained essentially by the *normal* convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8s}{n^2-4s^2}$ over each compact set $[0,a]$, $0<a<1/2$.

Comment: @zzchan Do you even know what does a "hint" even mean? Clearly, this is far from a hint. It's an answer. The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2-a^2}$ is very typical and common.

Comment: Nice to see you around Anastasiya-Romanova :)

Answer (score 3):

The identity:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(2k)}{k}x^{2k} = \log\left(\frac{\pi x}{\sin (\pi x)}\right) \tag{1}$$
holds for any $x$ such that $|x|<1$ by the Weierstrass product for the sine function.
By setting $x=\frac{1}{4}$ we recover the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
4\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh^{2}\pars{x/8} \over x\pars{\expo{x} - 1}}\,\dd x} =
4\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \expo{x} - 1}\,
{\sinh\pars{x/8} \over x}\,{\sinh\pars{x/8} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[4mm] = &\
4\int_{0}^{\infty}{x \over \expo{x} - 1}\,\half\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\expo{kx}\,\dd k
\,\half\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\expo{qx}\,\dd q\,\dd x =
\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x\expo{-\pars{1 - k - q}x} \over 1 - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x\,\dd k\,\dd q
\\[4mm] = &
\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\,\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\,\,\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\int_{0}^{\infty}
x\expo{-\pars{1 - k - q + n}x}\,\,\,\,\dd x\,\dd k\,\dd q =
\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\,\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\,\,\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}
{1 \over \pars{1 - k - q + n}^{\,2}}\,\dd k\,\dd q
\\[4mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\,\,\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{n + 7/8 - q}\pars{n + 9/8 - q}}\,\dd q
\\[4mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{-1/8}^{1/8}\pars{-4}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{{7 \over 8} - q} - \Psi\pars{{9 \over 8} - q}}\,\dd q =
\left.\vphantom{\huge A^{A}}
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{7/8 - q} \over \Gamma\pars{9/8 - q}}
\right\vert_{\ -1/8}^{\ 1/8}
\\[4mm] = &\
\ln\pars{{\Gamma\pars{3/4} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{5/4} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}} =
\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{3 \over 4}\,{1 \over 4}\,\Gamma\pars{1 \over 4}} =
\ln\pars{{1 \over 4}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/4}}} =
\ln\pars{2^{-3/2}\,\,\pi}
\\[4mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{\ln\pars{\pi} - {3 \over 2}\,\ln\pars{2}}
\end{align}